# How safe are Entity Framework Code First automatic migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deployment, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In our project we use a company-internal database for production, developing our model in EF6 Code First. Although we always backup the database before deploying we don't want any downtime, and we're afraid automatic migrations that run on application start may destroy data. Is this fear justified, or can we trust automatic migrations fully? So far we've modified Application_Start to generate SQL-scripts instead of migrating directly, but it becomes bothersome to do this every time and makes it harder to create a continuous deployment pipeline.

Comment: Before deploying to production you should perform a deploy test in a test environment that is exactly like the production environment.

Comment: What do I do after that? Do I just switch the pointers so that the test environment becomes the production environment and vice versa? Or do I redo the same operations on the production server?

Comment: Just think about how you would do it, if the production environment belongs to a customer. Develop => Deploy => Test Deploy => Rollout to customer

Comment: No, you can't fully trust migrations. Agree with Sir Rufo in that you need at least 3 environments: DEV which could just be a local db instance, TEST/UAT/QA which is where you roll out completed items, then PROD. Our DBAs require a script which we generate for them.

Comment: I don't trust automatic migrations especially when it comes to live DB schema changes, and it's imperative to keep all the data untouched.